# looping 10k array says error Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to handle an array with 10k items to set a new property on each row.

```
 _async.mapLimit(collection, 100, function (row, cb){
      row.type = "model";
      cb(null, row);
 }, function (err, collection){
      if(err) throw(err);
      console.log(collection);
 });
```

Then I get this error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What is this? I tried with async eachSeries but the same happens.

Comment: May it be that the `cb` function calls the loop again so that it is called recursively?

Comment: according async docs, iterator method has the callback function: https://github.com/caolan/async#mapLimit

Comment: You're not performing any asynchronous operation in your callback so couldn't you just replace this with a `for` loop that iterates over the array?

Comment: What happens when you decrease the limit from 100 to, say, 10?

Comment: using just a `for() in` loop it works fine. but how about if I need async operations?

Comment: with limit to 10 the same error happens

Comment: If you had async operations then the stack would be able to unwind each time the limit was hit and you wouldn't get the stack overflow.

Comment: Do not use sync function with async module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `async` library is expecting you to perform an asynchronous operation within your callback that will let the stack unwind while waiting for the async operations to complete.

If you only have synchronous processing to perform on each element, just use a `for` loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<collection.length; ++i) {
    collection[i].type = 'model';
}
```